# More visible desktop notifications in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, libnotify

The `notify-send` command lets script notify you about events.  However, in Gnome Shell 3.14.4, with fullscreen applications, such notifications will not be visible until you switch to Overview mode (`Super-S`). Is there a way to display such notifications above the current fullscreen window?

EDIT: I am open to alternative solutions than `notify-send`.

Comment: Set the urgency level to _critical_: `notify-send -u critical ...`

Comment: I had tried that: it makes the message more prominent in the Overview, but the message doesn't show above the current fullscreen application.

Comment: Works fine here, `gnome-shell 3.16.2` (not the classical mode though).

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.14.4 here.  By "classical-mode", do you mean Gnome Classic? If so, then no: I am using Gnome Shell.

Comment: Wait! It works.

Comment: I hadn't tested it properly.  I ran the command `notify-send` from the full screen terminal, but if I run `sleep 5 && notify-send` and then switch to another fullscreen application, then it works.  I suppose the latter way mimicks my use case.  Thank you.